# Compare raw hexadecimal values in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt4, hex

Below a `QbyteArray` is created and it contains a byte with the hexadecimal value `49`. `49` is one byte of data written in memory, it isn't an ASCII string representation of `49` (which is 2 bytes)

```
QByteArray data(QByteArray::fromHex("49"));
```

At some point I populate the `data` with additional bytes.

```
data.append(QByteArray::fromHex("7656"))
```

**How to compare a single byte with a hex value?**

Example:

This passes  (49 hex is 73 decimal):

```
if (data.at(0) == 73) 
qDebug() << "True"
```

But i need to work with hex values:

```
if (data.at(0) == WHAT_HERE?("49")) 
qDebug() << "True"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C/C++, a hexadecimal integer literal is prefixed with `0x`. So:

```
if (data.at(0) == 0x49)
  qDebug() << "true";
```

Answer (score 1):

if you know it at compile time then you can do `0x49`

if you get a QString to compare it with then

```
QString test="47";
bool ok;
int result = test.toInt(&ok,16);
if(ok && data.at(0)==result){
    //they are equal
}
```